# Open link with facebook app in android

Tags: android, facebook

Please see the two links below. When pasted in Whatsapp, first one opens with Facebook  app, but the second one opens with browser.

Opens in Facebook app:

https://m.facebook.com/SriSwamiji/posts/1099353043449548:0

Opens in Browser:

https://www.facebook.com/SriSwamiji/photos/a.186720728046122.67368.108460819205447/1099353043449548/?type=3

What makes the second link open in browser ? 
I want to open it via Facebook app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that is due to [deep linking](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html). In any of your apps you could add filters that trigger your app whenever the Android system tries to resolve an URL.

Probably the Facebook app has configured the deep link of the`http://m.*` urls

edit: I've tested it via adb and it is due to deep linking. You can test it with

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d <URL>
```

as explained in [the deep link documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html)

This is the output:

```
$ adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://m.facebook.com/SriSwamiji/posts/1099353043449548:0"
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://m.facebook.com/... }
Status: ok
Activity: com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.deeplinking.activity.StoryDeepLinkLoadingActivity
ThisTime: 127
TotalTime: 208
WaitTime: 253
Complete
```

As you can see the `Activity` launched is `com.facebook.katana` (the Facebook app).

```
$ adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://www.facebook.com/SriSwamiji/photos/a.186720728046122.67368.108460819205447/1099353043449548/?type=3"
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://www.facebook.com/... }
Status: ok
Activity: com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.document.DocumentActivity
ThisTime: 121
TotalTime: 179
WaitTime: 223
Complete
```

In this case `com.android.chrome` is launched

Also, if you take a look to the Facebook app manifest (with some app like [ManifestViewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.susatthi.ManifestViewer) you can see that it has some `intent-filter` to handle it:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="m.facebook.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/events"/>
            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="m.facebook.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/events"/>
            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="m.facebook.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/groups"/>
            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="m.facebook.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/groups"/>
            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="www.facebook.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/groups"/>
            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="www.facebook.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/groups"/>
            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="www.facebook.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/events"/>
            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="www.facebook.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/events"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

In your concrete case I would say that that link is handled in

```
    <activity
        android:theme="@2131625627"
        android:name="com.facebook.katana.ContactUriHandler"
        android:taskAffinity="com.facebook.task.ContactUriHandler"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data
                android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.facebook.profile"
                android:host="com.android.contacts"/>
            <data
                android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.facebook.presence"
                android:host="com.android.contacts"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and internally has support for posts but not for photos

Comment: no. Not due to http://m.  try this url. It will still open in browser. https://m.facebook.com/SriSwamiji/photos/a.186720728046122.67368.108460819205447/1099353043449548/?type=3

Comment: Thanks. This gives me the answer. I need to figure out way to get the link to the post from a photo using facebook graph api.

Comment: Thanks, especially for ManifestViewer link! I tried to figure out a way to place a link on the website that opens company's Facebook page in the Facebook app both on iOS and Android, so the final result is: `https://www.facebook.com/pg/companyname/home` for Android, `https://www.facebook.com/pg/companyname` for iOS and simple `https://www.facebook.com/companyname` for all other platforms.